# Workflow tiggered by another workflow runs on wrong branch

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a "Workflow B" that is automatically triggered when "Workflow A" is completed. Workflow A is triggered by each new Pull Request so the branch changes dynamically.

```
name: Workflow B
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ['Workflow A']
    types:
      - completed
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  first-workflow-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          cache: 'npm'
```

I would expect Workflow B to run on the same branch as Workflow A.
However, Workflow B runs on master.
How can I share the branch value between these workflows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have finally found the solution to my problem! Again, thanks to everyone who contributed so far.

So the solution relies on `workflow_run` context. The only addition we need is in Workflow_B where we access the trigger workflow's head branch:

```
name: Workflow B
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ['Workflow A']
    types:
      - completed
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  first-workflow-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_branch }}
      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          cache: 'npm'
```

Comment: That would work indeed, good catch. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub Actions does not seem to support directly sharing outputs between different workflow.

Workflows are designed to be self-contained, and while you can trigger one workflow after another using the `workflow_run` event, there's no built-in method for passing data directly from one workflow to another.

Workarounds, such as using artifacts or the repository itself to pass data, have certain restrictions and are often not reliable across separate workflows due to the concurrent nature of workflows.

You might consider [**`dawidd6/action-download-artifact`**](https://github.com/dawidd6/action-download-artifact), an action that downloads and extracts uploaded artifacts associated with a given workflow and commit or other criteria.

```yaml
name: Workflow B
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ['Workflow A']
    types:
      - completed
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  first-workflow-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          cache: 'npm'
      - name: Download artifact
        uses: dawidd6/action-download-artifact@v2
        with:
          workflow: 'Workflow A'
          workflow_conclusion: success
          name: branch # replace with the actual name of the artifact you want to download
```

with workflow A:

```yaml
jobs:
  first-workflow-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      ...
      - name: Set branch value as output
        id: set_branch
        run: |
          BRANCH_NAME="${{ github.head_ref }}"
          echo "branch_name=$BRANCH_NAME" > branch.txt
      - name: Archive production artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: branch
          path: branch.txt
```

Comment: `GITHUB_REF` may be replaced with [`GITHUB_REF_NAME`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables) i.e. `echo "branch_name=$GITHUB_REF_NAME" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT`. Why is that intermediate file `output.env` needed? Wouldn't `github.event.workflow_run.outputs.branch_name` give the value directly i.e. `echo "branch_name=${{ github.event.workflow_run.outputs.branch_name }}" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"`?

Comment: @Azeem Thank you for your feedback, I have edited the answer accordingly. The `output.env` was the rest of a previous try I did with GITHUB_ENV. I have removed it as you suggested.

Comment: Sure, no problem. With `GITHUB_REF_NAME`, that `cut` is not needed as it's already the name itself i.e. last part of the ref.

Comment: @Azeem "short ref name of the branch", right, I just realized that. Again, thank you.

Comment: Hello! Sorry for my late reply. Thank you all for your contribution. So, for Workflow A to echo the branch name worked for me like this `echo "branch_name=${{ github.head_ref }}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT`  (I forgot to mention that Workflow A is triggered by pull requests). However, on Workflow B when I try to retrieve the output with the suggested way, the branch_name is returned as empty. So I guess that I need to find a different way to access output on Workflow B?

Comment: @Gal OK, I have edited the answer to include a workaround. Let me know if it is working, and I will remove the first part.

Comment: @VonC Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, and as GH mentions "Note: You can only download artifacts in a workflow that were uploaded during the same workflow run." In my case, we have two different workflows that have to run on the same branch. To sum up, GITHUB_OUTPUT & artifacts didn't work. I do appreciate your suggestions though!!!

Comment: @Gal OK, I have rewritten the answer (I know, still using artifact). Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it also worked when I used this in my code.

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      ref: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_branch }}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).